# Scrollable html JLabel

Tags: html, swing, scroll, jlabel

I have a Jlabel packed with html.  I would like to scroll this content as you would with overflow : auto; in css.  I can't seem to get this to work.  Has anyone come across this?  I'd like to keep the content in HTML - for mark up - and use something light to scroll though it.

BTW: The Jlabel is in a popup - I can use something else other than a JLabel if needs be but would like to keep the html.

Cheers,

slotishtype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put that JLabel in a [`JScrollPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) instanciated that way :

```
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(myJLabel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Notice that, as this constructor [states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int)), those parameters can be changed afterwards.

Comment: +1 I know I can do that but I have that horrible-ugly-stupid-manky-swing-look-and-feel to deal with....

Comment: Then change that goddamn lookn'feel. it's not as if alternatives exist.